# OSX DNS can ping server until I make a DNS query via the browser

Tags: catalina, dns

I am having an issue on OSX Catalina (10.15.7) where connections to the DNS server initially work, but then time out or are extremely slow a few seconds after connecting to the network. It is isolated to this specific machine on this specific network, if I connect to another network, or use another machine, things work fine.

This is the output of `scutil --dns | head`

```
DNS configuration

resolver #1
  nameserver[0] : 8.8.8.8
  flags    : Request A records, Request AAAA records
  reach    : 0x00000002 (Reachable)
```

I ran `ping 8.8.8.8` continuously, while resetting the network adapter and then refreshing a browser tab:

```
*initial state*
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8): 56 data bytes
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
*if config en0 down*
ping: sendto: No route to host
Request timeout for icmp_seq 7
*if config en0 up*
Request timeout for icmp_seq 10
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=14 ttl=117 time=192.325 ms
...
*refresh browser tab*
Request timeout for icmp_seq 32
```

When the ping is responding, `dig` commands also work, but once it starts to time out, `dig` commands also fail.

It's clear that the DNS is reachable: it works for a few seconds, and other machines on the same network are having no problem. What could be the cause of the timeout that seems to start happening as soon as I make a DNS request via the browser, that does not start happening if I only use `dig`?